# Third order moment calculation - numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix

In python, I have an array X with N rows (the number of examples) and n columns (the number of features).

If I want to calculate the second order moment matrix C

C[i,j] = E(x_i x_j)

then I have two possibility:

- First, do the loop:

  ```
  for i in range(N):
      for j in range(n):
          for k in range(n):
              C[j,k] = C[j,k] + X[i,j]*X[i,k]/N
  ```
- Second, more simple, use numpy product matrix:

  ```
  import numpy np    
  C = np.transpose(X).dot(X)/N
  ```

  The second version in practice is extremely faster.

If now I want to calculate the third order moment matrix T

T[i,j,k] = E(x_i x_j x_k)

then the loop alternative is easy:

```
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(n):
      for k in range(n):
         for m in range(n):
            T[j,k,m] = T[j,k,m] + X[i,j]*X[i,k]*X[i,m]/N
```

Is there a fast way using numpy libraries to calculate this last tensor, like for the second order moment?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`NumPy's einsum notation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to solve both your second and third order cases.

**Second order :**

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',X,X)/N
```

**Third order :**

```
np.einsum('ij,ik,il->jkl',X,X,X)/N
```

As can be seen, it would be easier/intuitive to extend this to higher order cases with it.

Comment: I get a `ValueError: operand has more dimensions than subscripts given in einstein sum` when applying `np.einsum('ij,ik->jk',X,X)/N` to my array (an image).

Comment: @calocedrus Your image most probably would be 3D array. So, this won't work. Please post a new question.

Comment: indeed, thanks for pointing this out! It seems in this case the correct syntax should be `np.einsum('ij...,ik...->jk...',X,X)/N` and equivalent for the third order moment.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not perfect in terms of speed, but why not using `np.power(x, 3).sum() / N`? It is slower than the dot product, but faster than looping.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.random.rand(10000)
In [3]: x.dot(x.T)
Out[3]: 3373.6189738897856
In [4]: %timeit(x.dot(x.T))
The slowest run took 48.74 times longer than the fastest. This could   mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.39 µs per loop
In [5]: %timeit(np.power(x, 2).sum())
The slowest run took 4.14 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 140 µs per loop
In [6]: np.power(x, 2).sum()
Out[6]: 3373.6189738897865
```

Btw, that's how I calculate the moments...